# codec is deprecated

Tags: compiling

I am trying to run code for a video processing application on litmus rt using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579286/sdl2-0-alternative-for-sdl-overlay), however I am getting the error below.

```
bin/base_task.c: In function ‘main’:
bin/base_task.c:151:6: error: ‘codec’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
      if(pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
      ^
In file included from bin/base_task.c:20:0:
./include/libavformat/avformat.h:893:21: note: declared here
     AVCodecContext *codec;
                     ^
bin/base_task.c:159:4: error: ‘codec’ is deprecated [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
    pCodecCtx=pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;
    ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error *per se*, it's a warning that's treated as an error because of the `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` flag. If you disable that the build will proceed further.

Comment: can you please guide how to disable that ?

Comment: got it . Thankyou so much for your help :)

Comment: I am get below error which i guess is related to library link issue. can anyone help please

Comment: /home/nadiah/liblitmus/bin/base_task.c:127: undefined reference to `av_register_all'
/home/nadiah/liblitmus/bin/base_task.c:130: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/home/nadiah/liblitmus/bin/base_task.c:138: undefined reference to `avformat_open_input'
/home/nadiah/liblitmus/bin/base_task.c:144: undefined reference to `avformat_find_stream_info'
/home/nadiah/liblitmus/bin/base_task.c:162: undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'

Comment: @NadiahSarfraz you should [ask a new question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead of asking in a comment.